# Recargar componente en Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un formulario para guardar datos y una tabla que los muestra en la misma pagina, estoy intentando que al hacer click en el botón de enviar del formulario, la tabla se actualice con los nuevos datos inseridos, sin tener que actualizar la pagina entera.

He probado con lo siguiente: `this.$forceUpdate()` dentro de la función que se activa al hacer click en el botón del formulario, pero no funciona.

Tambien lo he intentado con un  `v-if="renderComponent"` en la tabla, y hacer lo siguiente en la función:

```
  forceRerender() {
    this.renderComponent = false;

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.renderComponent = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Usando lo anterior tampoco ha funcionado.

### Actualización

He usado el `v:key` en mi tabla:

```
<table class="table table-striped" :key="componentKey">
```

Y en una función:

```
refresh: function() {
      axios
        .get('api')
        .then(response => {
          this.data= response.data
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          this.errored = true
        })
        
        .finally(() => this.loading = false)

      console.log( this.componentKey);
      this.componentKey += 1;
      console.log( this.componentKey);
    }
```

Con esto he conseguido que la table se refresque, al enviar el formulario por segunda vez consecutiva, es decir:

1-Introduzco unos datos X en el formulario y los envío

2-Introduzco unos datos Y en el formulario y los envío

3-Se ven los datos X en la tabla

4-Introduzco unos datos Z en el formulario y los envío

5-Se ven los datos Y en la tabla

Y así sucesivamente...

¿A que se debe esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes intentar lo que recomienda la ultima parte de [esta página](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/). La parte que dice lo de hacer un componente con una `:key` dinámica.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque la he solucionado yo mismo